# How to fetch salesforce case details using CaseNumber via API call?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud, simple-salesforce

I am trying to fetch salesforce case details using **CaseNumber** which is currently throwing below error:

`[ { "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND", "message": "The requested resource does not exist" } ]`

[Using CaseNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXXV5.png)

I have tried making GET call using **Case** with all the parameters required and it works fine. The same does not work with CaseNumber.

[Using Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Vp6.png)

Can anyone help me on how i can get case details using CaseNumber??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CaseNumber is just a field on a Case object (a column in a database table), not a table on its own.

You either pull all fields (well all... all your user is allowed to see) of a single case with

`/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/Case{id}`

or you run a query

`/services/data/v59.0/query?q=SELECT+Id,CaseNumber,Subject,Description+FROM+Case+WHERE+CaseNumber='00128192'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. Also a quick question, is there an API to find the case owner details using OwnerID ??

Comment: `SELECT Subject, Owner.Name FROM Case WHERE...` Although Owner can be User or Queue so you might have to read a bit about "polymorphic SOQL": https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm. something like `SELECT typeof Owner WHEN User THEN Name, Username WHEN Queue THEN Name END FROM Case`